# permission denied even if with all permissions

Tags: python, permissions

I try to create a file with

```
path = 'temp.txt'
# cerca la posizione nel file di tutti i <img
with open(path, "w", encoding='utf-8') as tmp:
    tmp.write(sp)
tmp.close()
```

the file has these permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  647943 Jun 20 13:52 temp.txt
```

but I still get

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'temp.txt'
```

How can I solve this? I've tried to give 777 and 775 permissions both to the file and to the folder with chmod, but nothing changed

Comment: is the file still open in your computer somewhere? in some editor maybe? if so it is locked and can lead to this error. make sure it is not used by any other application.

Comment: P.S, you don't need `tmp.close()`. using `with` does that for you at the end of the block.

Comment: And what directory are you writing to?

Comment: I'm writing to the same directory where the py script is

Comment: @Jojo: How do you know it's the same directory. If you just use a filename and not a full path it will try to open the file in the working directory which might not be the same as the directory where the script is.